# Finding two analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find two analytic functions (the first one is analytic in the upper half plane the second one in the lower half plane) $f_+(z)$ and $f_-(z)$ which satisfy $f_+(x)-f_-(x)=\frac{1-\cos x}{x}$ and $f_{+-}(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}f_{+-}(x+-i\epsilon)$ with $x\in\mathbb R$

Whats the best way to start with these kind of problems? Integrate the RHS over an appropirate contour and see if this gives me something?

EDIT: I want to solve this problem in order to have some idea how to solve the integral equation $f(x)+\frac{\alpha}{i\pi}P.V\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(\xi)}{\xi-x}d\xi=\frac{1-\cos x}{x}$ where $\alpha$ is a constant different that +-1 and $f(x)=f_+(x)-f_-(x), \frac{1}{i\pi}P.V\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(\xi)}{\xi-x}d\xi=f_+(x)+f_-(x)$

Comment: Probably something to adjust. Why can't you put $f_+(z):=1+\frac {1-\cos(z)} z$ and $f_-(z):=1$?

Comment: @127.0.9.6: The function $f(z):=0$ is exceptional. For example, its zeros are not isolated.

Comment: I edited my post, maybe its clear now what I want to achieve

Comment: Perhaps you already know this, but I suggest reading up on the [Hilbert transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform).

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is something I miss, the functions 
$$
f_+(z)=\frac{1-\cos z}{2z}\quad \text{and}\quad f_-(z)=-\frac{1-\cos z}{2z},
$$
are both entire analytic, and
$$
f_+(x)-f_-(x)=\frac{1-\cos x}{x},
$$
for every $x\in\mathbb R$.